# error sudo apt-get upgrade or install

Tags: software-installation

I trying to run sudo apt-get upgrade. Even install i get always the below error. E: The value 'jessie' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources.

Comment: Are you still using Raspbian (Jessie)? About time you flashed a new sd card with the latest Raspberry Pi OS https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/

Comment: coreect jessie. I installed it some about 2 months ago

Comment: Why - that is several years old and out of date?

Comment: no.. i just tried to install mqtt borker and i got this message. Even if upgrade command

Comment: I think you need to start again with Raspberry Pi OS Bullseye as per my link.

Comment: so, there isn't any wat to fix it?

Comment: Doubt it on such an old OS. It will work fine on Bullseye 'sudo apt install mosquitto mosquitto-clients'

Comment: I have the following in the /etc/apt/sources.list: 
deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi

Answer (score 0):

Install something newer than Jessie, like Bullseye (or Buster or Stretch if you need an older one for some reason).
Jessie is under extended LTS and will be obsolete in 3 years.

Comment: Is any alternative solution to fix it instead format sd and install software?

Comment: @StergiosT https://stackoverflow.com/a/48377053/16946068 though you really should upgrade soon